# Regex To Get Embed SRC

Tags: regex, embed, src

I'm trying to write a PHP function that will scan the $content for an  tag and return the SRC url.

I've tried:

```
<embed.+?src="(.+?)".+?<\/embed>
```

But I get:

> Warning: preg_match_all()
>   [function.preg-match-all]: No ending
>   matching delimiter '>' found

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_match or preg_match_all need a delimiter

try: `/<embed.+?src="(.+?)".+?<\/embed>/`